# Summing and Average using python

Tags: python

- I have written a code that extracts floating point numbers from a
  text file and produces a list of the numbers.
- My challenge is summing the consecutive numbers and finding the
  average of the numbers.
- I am not allowed to use the sum function and I am new to python ..
  this the code I have written so far ,

***what can I do to add through the list***

```
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
#    print(line)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count + 1
#       print(count)

for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
#       print(line)
        xpos = line.find(' ')
#       print(xpos)
        num = line[xpos : ]
#       print(float(num))
        fnum = float(num)       
#       print(fnum)
        
        total = 0
        for i in fnum:
            total += int(i) 
            print(total)
```

***Error:"float object not iterable on line 24" ... line 24 is the 4th for loop***

Comment: what's the problem in the code

Comment: "float object not iterable on line 24" ... line 24 is the 4th for loop

Comment: approve my edit

Comment: the first part works, I have outputed the list .. my challenge is summing the members of the list without using the sum function .. and then find the average

Comment: Please also upload the text file sample.

Comment: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt ..... when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

Answer (score 2):

First an open file is iterable only once, and your code shows 4 loops starting with `for line in fh:`. After first loop, the file pointer will reach the end of file, and the following loops should immediately return. For that reason `with` should be prefered.

Next somewhere in the loop you get a float value in `fnum`. Just initialize `total` before starting the loop, and add `fnum` when you get it:

```
total = 0
with open(fname) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
    #       print(line)
            xpos = line.find(' ')
    #       print(xpos)
            num = line[xpos : ]
    #       print(float(num))
            fnum = float(num)       
    #       print(fnum)
            total += fnum
    #       print(total)
```

`with` ensures that the file will be cleanly closed at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`fnum` is a float. It's not an array, therefore it's not iterable and cannot be iterated in a for loop.

You probably don't need an array to determine the total and the average:

```
fname = "c:\\mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)

count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        xpos = line.find(' ')
        num = line[xpos : ]
        fnum = float(num)       
        total += fnum
        count += 1

print("Total = " + str(total))
print("Average = " + str(total / count))
print("Number of items = " + str(count))
```

Comment: print(fnum)  outputs the list of 27 floating point numbers ,, how can I arrange them in an array or add through them consecutively without using the sum function. I just tried this but still says not iterable for the last for loop                                                def figs():
             print(fnum)
            
         total = 0
         for i in figs:
             total += int(i)
             print(total)

Comment: On the line that it errors, `fnum` is equal to `0.8475`.

Comment: how do I arrange the output in an array so that I can then iterate through it with a for loop

Comment: You probably don't need an array to determine the total and the average, I've updated my solution the total and average.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use **startsWith** in this case. Better to use **split** for each line of the file. Each line will split all the words to a list. Then using the indexes you look for, **X-DSPAM-Confidence:**. If it exists then take the corresponding value of interest. In this case it is index number 1. Below is the code:

```
total = 0
number_of_items = 0

with open("dat.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        if fields != []:
            if fields[0] == "X-DSPAM-Confidence:":
                number_of_items += 1
                total += float(fields[1])

print(total)
print(number_of_items)      

avg = (total/number_of_items)    
print(avg)
```

I saved your data in a text file names, "dat.txt".

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: thanks for assisting.. there are 27 lines containing "X-DSPAM.."  first code gives an error message :::TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.constructor')

Comment: I noticed this message comes up when I use the "with function"

Comment: my code outputs the list of 27 floating point numbers, my challenge is grouping them in an array so I can iterate through them  with a for loop

Comment: @user1855085  I have modified the code and tried writing the outputs into a text file so I can read them but I encounter an error code on line 20 ...((ExternalError: todo; haven't implemented non-read opens on line 20)).. this is my new code

Comment: for line in fh:    
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count + 1
#       print(count)
  
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
#       print(line)
  
  xpos = line.find(' ')
#  print(xpos)
  num = line[xpos : ]
#  print(float(num))
  fnum = float(num)

  file = open("kxk.txt", "w")
  data = fnum
  file.write(data)
  file.close()
          
  h = open('kxk.txt', 'r')
  content = list(h)
  total = 0
  
  for line in content:
   if line > 0:
    total += line
    print(total)

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data. Then I code at my side and and get back to you.

Comment: This is the link with of the sample data. enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.   https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

Comment: I have written a code that works but it is too long to post so I will post it as two messages.                                                                                     count = 0
total = 0
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:    
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count + 1
#        print(count)  
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
#       print(line)

Comment: xpos = line.find(' ')
#  print(xpos)
  num = line[xpos : ]
#  print(float(num))    
  list1 = (0.8475, 0.6178, 0.6961, 0.7565, 0.7626, 0.7556, 0.7002, 0.7615, 0.7601, 0.7605, 0.6959, 0.7606, 0.7559, 0.7605, 0.6932, 0.7558, 0.6526, 0.6948, 0.6528, 0.7002, 0.7554, 0.6956, 0.6959, 0.7556, 0.9846, 0.8509, 0.9907)
  total = 0
  for i in list1 :
   if i < 27:
    total = total + i
#    print(total)
average = float(total/count)                  @user1855085

Comment: now I need to know something, do you want all the numbers from 27 lines to together and then calculate avg ??? or add for each line and calculate avg ? in the later case there will be 27 results

Comment: first case @Boomerang20thCentury

Comment: I edited the answer according to your data and inputs. It is perfectly working at my side. For this data, the avg resulted to 0.7507185185185187

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Boomerang20thCentury

Comment: @Palani, if this solution is working, please mark it as solved, click the tick mark on the left side of the answer. It helps for other users to search for similar solutions